# Export Web Text to excel vbs

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all i have been searching the web like mad and came up with the following vba code in excel the problem is it exports the table but not the text within the table it seems to only recover all text in the table that you can click on but not any set text.

If it will be easier for anyone to assist with their own code to do what i need it to help will be highly appreciated.

```
Sub my_Procedure()
Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object

 Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim paras As Object, para As Object, i As Long
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "https://www.plus500.co.uk/?id=113082&tags=g_sr%2B1711614451_cpi%2BUKSearchBrand_cp%2B70887725030_agi%2BPlus500Core_agn%2Bplus%20500_ks%2Bkwd-842162906_tid%2Be_mt%2Bc_de%2Bg_nt%2B_ext%2B1006989_loc%2BUURL&%D7%90&gclid=CjwKCAjw1cX0BRBmEiwAy9tKHqylty6Mz9TbIA5VzgOiqxOcWg7biR652Hg9tksIR97hlUuAHLZilhoCTq0QAvD_BwE", False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
Set paras = html.getElementsByTagName("Tbody")
i = 1
For Each para In paras
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value = para.innerText
    i = i + 1
Next

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
'Replace the URL of the webpage that you want to download
Web_URL = VBA.Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1))

'Create HTMLFile Object
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

Dim tdd As String
'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
    .send
    HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
End With

Column_Num_To_Start = 1
iRow = 2
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iTable = 0

'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
    With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(iTable)
        For Each Tr In .Rows
            For Each Td In Tr.Cells
             Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
                iCol = iCol + 1
            Next Td
            iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next Tr
    End With
    iTable = iTable + 1
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tab1

MsgBox "Process Completed"
Call StartTimer

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi braX thanks for the changes it seems to work beter thanks but please have a look it exports the table with each instruments name and the values buy, sell, trade but it does not show the value for each instrument. I am seeking to have a vba excell code that can run and store each current value as it changes in the stock market in order for me to perform calculations on it in excell. please advise

Comment: Your question is very broad. Which instruments do you need? Do you only need the "Most Popular" for example? Do you want all those tabs available in that widget in the home page? The reason you're only getting the headers of the table is because they are static content which is available in source HTML of the page. The actual values are dynamically requested and loaded/displayed by a script. You need a separate HTTP request to get them in JSON format.